# Import JSF 2.3 in POM file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

I tried to import JSF dependency in order to use JSF 2.3 but I get error:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

Failed to collect dependencies for [org.glassfish:javax.faces:jar:2.3.0 (compile)
```

Which implementation should be better to use?

Comment: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```